# Could not see my Ubuntu after upgrading my windows 10

Tags: boot-repair

pls help solve this problem
I upgraded my windows 10 after which I cannot see my ubuntu again
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/dC6fvFNg7S/

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the Windows update killed your Ubuntu partition. This has been happening with the major Windows updates, and when users have MBR formatted hard disks. Microsoft has known about this problem for years, and has chosen not to fix it. Thanks Microsoft!

Recovery can be complicated, and fraught with possible error... but it is possible to get Ubuntu back.

You'll need to boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD and install `testdisk`. Read [these instructions](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step) on the procedure. You'll need to have some technical knowledge of disk partitioning to resolve the problem.

Search here on AU for "testdisk" and read other users experiences with this tool.